About the hinge loss and slack variables
I'll be denoting the $ith$ training example, target label and slack variable as $\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}$, $y^{(i)}$ and $\xi_i$ respectively.
Hinge Loss :
The hinge loss function in the context of Support Vector Machines(SVMs) is formulated as :
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{\vec w}, b\,; \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}, y ^{(i)}) = \max(0, 1-y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
And the corresponding cost function is given as :
$$
J(\mathbf{\vec w}, b) = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{\vec w}\|^{2}_{2} + C\sum_{i=1}^{m}\max(0, 1 - y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
Slack Variables :
Slack variables allow a degree of misclassification and the only formal way to calculate that I could find is expressed as :
$$
\xi_i = \max(0, 1 - y ^{(i)} (\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b))
$$
I have two main questions from the above observations :

Why are the formulae to calculate the hinge loss and slack variables exactly the same? Moreover, the slack value is considered 0 if the point is correctly classified and has a positive value if its incorrectly classified. But isn't that the exact same working of the hinge loss?


I was under the assumption that in order to allow a "degree of misclassification", we must incorporate the slack variables in the decision function and a "slacked" hinge loss function. Is that incorrect?

"Slacked" Decision Function :
$$
h_{\mathbf{\vec w}, b}(\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}) = \text{sgn}(y^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w}\cdot\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b) + \xi_i)
$$
"Slacked" Hinge Loss Function :
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{\vec w}, b\,; \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}, y ^{(i)}) = \max(0, 1 - y ^{(i)}(\mathbf{\vec w} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)} + b) + \xi _{i})
$$
